# How to iterate through multiple selects and set option based on the value from DB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have been working on my project where I have page that contain a table with multiple rows and each row has select(drop down).

Each of these select has one option so far. That option has a value assigned from DB.

I want to loop through all select on the page after page load. Then if select has value -1, I want to default my drop down to NO, and second option should be YES with value 0.

Here is how my table looks like:

```
1   8:00 AM - 8:30 AM    SELECT 
2   8:30 AM - 9:00 AM    SELECT 
3   9:00 AM - 9:30 AM    SELECT 
4   9:30 AM - 10:00 AM   SELECT
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
        <label>
            <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
                <option value="~(USER_ID)"></option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried something like this in JQuery:

```
<script>
    $j( document ).ready(function() {
        $j('.dropBox').each(function() {
            if($j(this).val() == "-1" || $j(this).val() == ""){
                $j('.dropBox').append('<option value="-1" selected="selected">No</option><option value="0">Yes</option>');
                }

                if($j(this).val() == "0" ){
                    $j('.dropBox').find("option").eq(0).hide();
                    $j('.dropBox').append('<option value="0" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="-1">No</option>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Code above gave me many Yes and No options in each row. That is not what I want. What would be the other way to get this to work? Should I maybe check values by each ID or something else?

```js
$j = jQuery;

$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j('.dropBox').each(function() {
    if ($j(this).val() == "-1" || $j(this).val() == "") {
      $j('.dropBox').append('<option value="-1" selected="selected">No</option><option value="0">Yes</option>');
    }

    if ($j(this).val() == "0") {
      $j('.dropBox').find("option").eq(0).hide();
      $j('.dropBox').append('<option value="0" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="-1">No</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="0"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="-1"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="2"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were making modifications to *all* `.dropBox`'s when you only intended to do so on the current `.dropBox` of the loop's iteration.

For the `.each` loop, the callback gets the iterator index as the first argument and the element as the second argument. The context is the element, too, which you seemed to have gotten right but then didn't use?

```js
$j = jQuery;

$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j('.dropBox').each(function(index, dropBox) {
    // Instead of appending options to every .dropBox, only do it for this one.
    var $select = $j(this); // or $j(dropBox);
    var val     = $select.val();
    if (val == "-1" || val == "") {
      $select.append('<option value="-1" selected="selected">No</option><option value="0">Yes</option>');
    } else if (val == "0") {
      $select.find("option").eq(0).remove(); // You can't hide an option. I am presuming you wanted the first option removed?
      $select.append('<option value="0" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="-1">No</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="0"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="-1"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>~(ORDER)</td>
    <td>~(TIMESLOT)</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="blockTime_~(recordID)" name="" class="dropBox">
          <option value="2"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tested this code and works for me too. I'm still confused why my code was making duplicates in each drop down. Can you explain how that part in your code where you did var select = $j(this); // or $j(dropBox); var val     = $select.val(); is different from mine and what that actually does? I can see that you included index and dropBox in function. Index give us number of elements but what dropBox actually is?  Thank you for help with this problem!

Comment: You were doing `$('.dropBox').append`, as opposed to `$(this).append`. That was appending options to every single `.dropBox` as soon as a `.dropBox` with a value of `0` or `-1` was found. The same value would be found in all the remaining selects, which would append to *all* the selects each remaining iteration. (`index` didn't have any value here, was just including it to show we could use `this` or the 2nd argument to emphasize re-using the current element/iterator.)

Comment: So I could just use $j(this) instead of $j('.dropBox') in my code and that would fix the problem?

Comment: That is correct. (You wouldn't notice a difference here, but It's better to assign a variable (e.g. `var $select = $(this);`) and reuse the variable as opposed to creating a new jQuery object every time you need to use jQuery (e.g. `$select.val(); $select.append()` as opposed to `$(this).val(), $(this).append()`. The latter creates a jQuery object twice.)